# Preact: Typing the props of a component that wraps a native component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, preact

With React you are able to use `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"img">` to elegantly type a component that passes through props to a native element.

How are you supposed to do this with Preact?

Answer (score 1):

There is exactly no utility type similar to `ComponentPropsWithoutRef` provided in React typings. But you can make use of `IntrinsicElements` interface defined in `JSXInternal` namespace.

```
import { JSXInternal } from 'preact/src/jsx';

type ImgAttrs = JSXInternal.IntrinsicElements['img'];

let x = {} as ImgAttrs;
```

This works with Preact version `10.x.x`.